# Using Google SQL to cast TIME (1-24) scale into string(five categories)

Tags: string, google-bigquery, casting, number-formatting

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3e0b.png)
[Trimmed Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gDit.png)

I would like to cast the start_time_of_day into an integer into order to split it into 5 categories:

Early Morning      03:01 - 07:00
Morning            07:01 - 12:00
Afternoon          12:01 - 17:00
Evening            17:01 - 22:00
Late Night         22:01 - 03:00

[Proposed operators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk35R.png)

Then recast them back to string to say the category name

I'm not sure how to go about this. Do I need to create a separate table once I cast them as numeric and then cast them back into string? Or, can I do this within one query?

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
with categories as (
  select time(3,0,1) as start, time(7,0,0) as finish, 'early morning' as category union all
  select time(7,0,1), time(12,0,0), 'morning' union all
  select time(12,0,1), time(17,0,0), 'afternoon' union all
  select time(17,0,1), time(22,0,0), 'evening' union all
  select time(22,0,1), time(23,59,59), 'night' union all
  select time(0,0,0), time(3,0,0), 'night'
)
select t.*, category
from your_table t
left join categories
on time(timestamp_trunc(started_at, second)) between start and finish
```

[image]